# Generate Allure Report with XUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, .net-6.0, xunit

Can anyone explain how can I generate allure report with .NET 6.0 XUnit?
I can generate either html test results as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSkrc.png)

or with an extension of .trx. I am trying to generate beautiful allure reports and everywhere I look is missing xunit documentation for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Bot is correct  please add more code, explain what you already tested, etc. And did you follow the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows)?